# Email send via SmtpClient does not display images

Tags: c#, image, smtpclient

The following code produces an email which the image is visible via webmail clients such as gmail but is not visible via thunderbird or outlook clients.  A broken link is visible in these clients and for some reason it does not prompt me to load images.  When the same email is forwarded from another client it does prompt me to load the images and everything behaves as expected.

```
 class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mesg = new MailMessage("destination@somewhere.com","from@somewhere.com");
        mesg.Body = "<img src='http://localhost/images/bangs.JPG' />";
        mesg.Subject = "Image Spike Test";
        mesg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
        client.Send(mesg);

    }
}
```

Here is the email source that is produced by this code.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: destination@somewhere.com
To: from@somewhere.come
Date: 9 Jul 2011 09:25:08 -0500
Subject: Image Spike Test
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<img src=3D'http://localhost/images/bangs.JPG' />
```

Comment: Your code works for me, although I changed the SMTP Client details to point to Gmail servers. Outlook had that bar at the top that needs to be clicked to display the image. Also, I changed the image URL; yours seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you send a mail like that, your email reader will have to go to `register.cwh.com` to ask for the image.  That would tell `register.cwh.com` when, and from where, the email was being read.  Outlook and other email clients protect your privacy and do not retrieve the image.  I'm somewhat suprised that GMail does load them.

A proper fix is to send the image as an attachment.  Outlook will display images from attachments.

Comment: OP claims that Outlook doesn't prompt to load images. I tested the same code (with the changes mentioned in my comment) and Outlook offered the usual bar at the top which says `Click here to download pictures. To help protect your privacy, Outlook prevented automatic download of some pictures in this message`

Comment: I've edited the question.  The url to the image isn't relevant to the question as I've verified that the resource is there.  The original host was mapped to my local which was why you were getting 404's.

Comment: Plenty of email is sent with images which aren't embedded but ref an external server.  Clients prompt you to download the images when this happens.  However that isn't the problem.  Like I said I don't receive the prompt.  Even though I do on emails sent from other clients.